# read_fwf and decimal-less formatting

Tags: python, pandas

Fixed format data files sometimes come without explicit decimal points and instead rely on a formatting string to parse an integer into a float (e.g., %4.2f).  Is such functionality built into read_fwf?  I.e., is there a simple way of parsing 1004 as 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom converter that will convert on the fly as you read the file:

```
def convert_to_decimals(x):
    return x.format('4%.2f')

df = pd.read_fwf('myfile', converters={'col_to_convert':convert_to_decimals})
```

So what happens here is that we are defining a conversion function and then setting the `converters` param by passing a `dict` which contains as a key the column we want to convert and the function name as the converting function.

See the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html)

Comment: That does not seem to have worked. For example, '1004'.format('%4.2f')  or '1004'.format('4%.2f') returns '1004'.  So when I applied the above, 'col_to_convert' had a dtype of object rather than a float.  On the other hand,

    def convert_to_decimals(x):
    return float(x)/100

    df = pd.read_fwf('myfile', converters={'col_to_convert':convert_to_decimals})
makes does the correct conversion.  What would be more interesting would be a function convert_to_decimals(x,formatstring) which could more flexibly do the conversion.  (Sorry for the poor formatting.)

Comment: So you want the dtype to be a float, try this `def convert_to_decimals(x):
    return float(x[:-2] + '.' + x[-2:])`

Comment: @TedTo for custom formatting you would have to define this and use as a converter param when reading the file or doing it post read